# <FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase.h> is not found (lexcial or preprocessor issuses)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cocoapods

[image][image]friends, i install the pod file called 
SwiftCountrySelector for selecting countries but after pod installation i got the error called FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase.h is not found.help me friends

my pod file is above

Comment: Can you please post your podfile?

Comment: GeoFire hasn't been updated for the latest release of the Firebase SDK. You'll need to use an older version of Firebase for GeoFire to work at the moment.

Comment: how to update geofire pod file

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using the `Geofire` 2.0 cocoapod as well but I was able to solve it by closing out of xcode and running `pod update` to get my `firebaseDatabase` pod up to version 4.0 as well as `pod install` to make sure both the newest Firebase database and Geofire pods are in the project. Your podfile should look like this:

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'
```

You'll then want to open the xcode project, and navigate to:

> Pods/ FirebaseDatabase/ Frameworks/ FirebaseDatabase.framework

Click on the `FirebaseDatabase.framework` and then check the GeoFire target membership check box on the right. Clean the app and re-run and it should work.

[image]

Check out this github post for more info on it. I actually found this post straight from the Firebase documentation:

[Geofire Cocoapod 2.0 Isn't Available](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/48)